# Apply multiple search in fields

Tags: java, kotlin

```
fun getMatchingContactsFromSearch(startDate: String?, endDate: String?, whereMet: String?, eventName: String?, product: String?, service: String?): Observable<List<String>> {
{
    if ((eventName!!.isNotEmpty()) && whereMet!!.isEmpty() && (startDate!!.isEmpty() && endDate!!.isEmpty())&& product!!.isEmpty()&& service!!.isEmpty()) {

    } else if ((whereMet!!.isNotEmpty()) && eventName!!.isEmpty() && (startDate!!.isEmpty() && endDate!!.isEmpty())&& product!!.isEmpty()&& service!!.isEmpty()) {

    } else if ((startDate!!.isNotEmpty() && endDate!!.isNotEmpty()) && eventName!!.isNotEmpty() && whereMet!!.isEmpty()&& product!!.isEmpty()&& service!!.isEmpty()) {

    } else if ((startDate!!.isNotEmpty() && endDate!!.isNotEmpty()) && eventName!!.isEmpty() && whereMet!!.isNotEmpty()&& product!!.isEmpty()&& service!!.isEmpty()) {

    } else if ((eventName!!.isNotEmpty() && whereMet!!.isNotEmpty()) && ((startDate!!.isEmpty() && endDate!!.isEmpty()))&& product!!.isEmpty()&& service!!.isEmpty()) {

    } else if (eventName!!.isEmpty() && whereMet!!.isEmpty() && (startDate!!.isNotEmpty() && endDate!!.isNotEmpty())&& product!!.isEmpty()&& service!!.isEmpty()) {

    } else if (eventName!!.isNotEmpty() && whereMet!!.isNotEmpty() && startDate!!.isNotEmpty() && endDate!!.isNotEmpty()&& product!!.isEmpty()&& service!!.isEmpty()) {

    } else  {

    }
}
```

this is my Searching Code for multiple item i have 2 more field to Search like product and service i have to apply condition for that also but its seems very complicated to apply search condition for two more field can any one suggest me  how to apply search condition for two more field or give me some other way so that we can search that from listOfData .

Comment: Your requirement is that at least two fields are not empty? Lots of ways to do that. How about simply counting the number of non-empty fields and requiring that it be >= 2?

Comment: @PaulHicks please suggest me coz condition is to much increase so i want apply search with two more field

Comment: I can't write the exact solution. I don't know the specs for your `Observable<List<String>>` are. I would need more information. A big list of conditions is not likely to be the correct solution.

Comment: please tell me some solution for this @PaulHicks

Answer (score 1):

What you need to implement is a simple `and` criteria (I am assuming you want `and` semantics for your search.

This approach I will show you will work for any other search like this in your app.

Imagine you have a class `Data` like so:

```
data class Data(val a: String? = null, val b: String? = null, val c: String? = null)
```

Let's introduce a predicate type which is just an alias for a function:

```
typealias Predicate<T> = T.() -> Boolean
```

So a predicate that checks property `a` of `Data` class may look like this:

```
val isASomething : Predicate<Data> = { a == "something" }
val data = Data(a = "something")
data.isASomething() // true
```

Since we want `and` semantics, lets create a helper function that will combine any number of predicates with a logical `and`:

```
fun <T> and(vararg predicates: Predicate<T>): Predicate<T> {
  return predicates.fold({ true }) { previous: Predicate<T>, next: Predicate<T> ->
    {
      previous() && next()
    }
  }
}
```

Putting it all together, you can write a method that uses your criteria components to search a list of objects:

```
fun List<Data>.findByProps(aQuery: String? = null, bQuery: String? = null, cQuery: String? = null): List<Data> {

  val predicates = mutableListOf<Predicate<Data>>()
  if (aQuery != null) predicates += { a == aQuery }
  if (bQuery != null) predicates += { b == bQuery }
  if (cQuery != null) predicates += { c == cQuery }
  if (predicates.isEmpty()) throw IllegalArgumentException("At least one query must have a value")
  val criteria = and(*predicates.toTypedArray())
  return this.filter { it.criteria() }
}
```

Let's test it:

```
val data = listOf(
    Data("a", "b", "c"),
    Data("a", "1", "2"),
    Data("a", "1", "c")
)
println(data.findByProps(aQuery = "a")) // [Data(a=a, b=b, c=c), Data(a=a, b=1, c=2), Data(a=a, b=1, c=c)]
println(data.findByProps(bQuery = "1")) // [Data(a=a, b=1, c=2), Data(a=a, b=1, c=c)]
println(data.findByProps(aQuery = "a", cQuery = "c")) // [Data(a=a, b=1, c=2), Data(a=a, b=1, c=c)]
```

You can now easily adapt this approach to your case:

```
class Contact {
  ...
}

fun List<Contact>.search(startDateQuery: String? = null, endDateQuery: String? = null, whereMetQuery: String? = null, eventNameQuery: String? = null, productQuery: String? = null, serviceQuery: String? = null) {
      val predicates = mutableListOf<Predicate<Contact>>()
      if (startDateQuery != null) predicates += { startDate == startDateQuery }
      if (endDateQuery != null) predicates += { endDate == endDateQuery }
      if (whereMetQuery != null) predicates += { whereMet == whereMetQuery }
      if (eventNameQuery != null) predicates += { eventName == eventNameQuery }
      if (productQuery != null) predicates += { product == productQuery }
      if (serviceQuery != null) predicates += { service == serviceQuery }
      if (predicates.isEmpty()) throw IllegalArgumentException("At least one query must have a value")
      val criteria = and(*predicates.toTypedArray())
      return this.filter { it.criteria() }
}
```

And use it:

```
val contacts : List<Contact> = getContacts()
val metAtHall = contacts.search(whereMetQuery = "Hall")
```

Comment: This seems like overkill. While we don't know exactly what's needed due to the lack of posted requirements, it looks something like "if exactly one choice is select, do a search based on that one select, else complain". It is probable that a good solution might be to implement methods like `assertExactlyOneSelection()` and `getSelection().search()`. These massive chunks of code seem very procedural and.. well.. a bit old-fashioned.

Comment: @PaulHicks thanx for Solution but i need  Search like different ways i have 6  parameter  so that   there is date in listofobject i have to search like the given date lies between date item or not what ever we select only search by those item

Comment: I was wondering if the logic for each type of search could be in six different places (more object oriented), rather than in one place with a 6-way switch.